# Realm DB with embedded server

Tags: server, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I currently have a Ktor server that handles user transactions, debts, etc. for a KMM debt tracking app. I want to use Realm DB with Sync as my database, but from what I understand, realm is an embedded database that should be used directly in my KMM backend, and wouldn't make much sense in a standalone server. However, considering that Ktor is an embedded server, would it still make sense to use Realm with Ktor, or would I just be better off without a server between application and realm? All design advice is welcome, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, asking for opinions here on SO will result in the question being closed, see [How to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Additionally, the questions' use case  is a bit vague; Realm is Local First database and functions in two ways; Local only, meaning all data is stored on the device, or Ream Sync which leverages MongoDB Atlas to sync its data to the Atlas server. Neither of those is a 'embedded server' per se so it's not clear how Realm work in your environment. Can you clarify the question and your use case?

Comment: @Jay I have a Ktor embedded server in which I want to use Realm with Sync to connect to an Atlas cluster. Since Realm is a local first db, would it be better to just use Realm directly in my mobile backend, or is there still some value and sense in creating a server to deal with database actions?

Comment: If I understand what's being asked; there is no "realm server" for you to create. It's either a local database on the device itself, or, it's sync'd database (local + sync) to Atlas. So the 'server' component is Atlas when you're using sync. Realm is the SDK portion that allows you to work with Atlas in a much easier fashion than directly hitting endpoints to get/set data. However, that's an option as well if you need it. So I think the answer is yes, use a Realm SDK 'directly'.

Comment: The flow right now is: mobile launches Ktor embeddedServer to make request -> Realm is queried inside Ktor server code -> Realm syncs with Atlas. I wanted to create a server initially just for practice, but maybe it's just more practical for mobile to directly call Realm and forego a server entirely? Hopefully this makes my question clearer

Comment: Well, not really lol. *Realm is queried inside Ktor server code*. Realm is an SDK so I am not sure how that would work. Perhaps you mean query Atlas? And *call Realm* - you can't call Realm - Realm is a SDK environment; Realm Database is the actual storage of the local data, but that can't be called either. Perhaps a quick review of what Realm is and the problem is solves would clarify things a bit? [What is Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/introduction/)

Comment: Read and write to the local database is what I mean. My question still stands: is there any value in having database stuff in a server, or just use Realm SDK as BaaS directly in my client code

Comment: I *think* the answer is no but the questions are kinda vague; *having database stuff* - what is 'stuff'? *In a server* - what is 'a server', Atlas?  Ktor? *use Realm SDK as BaaS* - to be clear Realm is NOT a Baas; that is not the role it plays and not what it's designed to do. Realm is for the Frontend; the client side logic and supports the UI, whereas Atlas is the backend the 'Baas'. You do not need Realm to use Atlas so if you are looking for cloud Baas, Atlas is your solution. If you want a tightly integrated total solution then MongoDB Realm SDK with sync or store locally is the solution.